# Invoking Android Application Based on Id on NFC Tag

Tags: android, android-intent, nfc

Can we give an Id to an Android application with same Id on my NFC Tag. Now the usecase is when I scan the NFC Tag the android OS should match the Id from Tag with the application Id and start that application.

Right now I'm starting the particular application with the use of custom MIME Type. But I want to invoke application with the help of Id on the Tag.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for [Android Application Records](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html#aar). This will let you specify what app to start on the tag, so you don't need to keep an ID<->app mapping.

Comment: but Android Application Record is available on Android ICS.. I am using Android 2.3

Comment: In that case you might have to create a dispatcher app that matches tag ID against a database of some sort and starts the appropriate app.